# Angular - using how to call function on component created dynamically using ng-dynamic-component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I am using the npm package [ng-dynamic-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component) to create dynamic components.

I am in a situation where i want to call a specific function on the dynamically created component using this package.

I have experimented with a lot of different ways but so far found no solution.

Does anyone have any idea if it is possible to call a function on a component that is created dynamically using the mentioned package?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-dynamic-component has a "Component Creation Event" `ndcDynamicCreated` that passes a `ComponentRef<any>` as a parameter.

From the docs:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<ndc-dynamic [ndcDynamicComponent]="component"
                          (ndcDynamicCreated)="componentCreated($event)"
                          ></ndc-dynamic>`
})
class MyComponent {
  component = MyDynamicComponent1;
  componentCreated(compRef: ComponentRef<any>) {
    // utilize compRef in some way ...
  }
}
```

Utilizing compRef in some way would be calling a function of the `compRef.instance` property in your case.

Comment: I have tested it out and can confirm that on the componentref generated i am able to take .instance and then call a function on the dynamically created component. Thanks!